# spring security login fails on custom mobile login page

Tags: jquery, grails, jquery-mobile, spring-security

I have a login page which uses spring security core. Now I want to create a mobile login page. So I used the jquery mobile. I copied the form from auth.gsp and paste it on the mobile page I created. I edited the form which now look like this:

```
    <form method="POST" action="${resource(file: 'j_spring_security_check')}">

    Username:
    <g:textField  class="xlarge" name='j_username' id='j_username' value='${request.remoteUser}' />

    Password:
    <input type='password' class="xlarge"  name='j_password' id='j_password' value='${request.remoteUser}' />

    <g:submitButton name="login" value="Login" /></td>

    </form>
```

But when I tried to login, an error message appears that simply says "Error loading Page". I think it was generated by jquery mobile. But when I tried to refresh, it redirects to the main page which means that the login was successful, it just that its not redirecting automatically to the main page after logged in successfully.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: What are the actual responses you are getting from the server? Try using Chrome (and pretending the browser is a mobile client) and inspect the network calls (via the Chrome Inspector).

Comment: I have experienced this too.